# Why can't my fifa my player play for Tahiti?

Tags: fifa-14

Is it because they didn't qualify for the World Cup in fifa 14? Does that mean my player will never play for a national team?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you cannot play as Tahiti as it is not in FIFA 14 as a playable country.